# PS1 does not echo backslash

Tags: bash, ps1

I want this Bash prompt:

```
/\ /\
root@debian$:
```

I do:

```
PS1="/\  /\\n${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h\$:"
```

Or:

```
PS1="/\  /\\\n${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h\$:"
```

But I have:

```
/\  /
root@debian$:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PS1 itself does an extra layer of interpretation:

```
PS1="/\  /\\\\\n${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h\$:"
          ^^^^ 4 backslashes
```

Or better yet:

```
PS1="/\\\\  /\\\\\n${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h\$:"
```

Output I get:

```
/\  /\
ibug@ubuntu$:
```

**Pro-tip**: Use single quotes to save yourself *quite some* escapes:

```
PS1='/\\  /\\\n'"${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}"'\u@\h\$:'
    ^          ^^                                  ^^        ^
```